# Get length of IEnumerable?

Tags: ironpython

What's the fastest way to get the length of an .net `IEnumerable<T>` in IronPython? The Python standard `len()` function doesn't seem to work on it.

I know I can do

```
len(list(my_enumerable))
```

or

```
list(my_enumerable).Count
```

But that might be slower than necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you know if it *actually* implements `IEnumerable<T>`? If so, you could use [`Enumerable.Count(IEnumerable<T> source)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) (part of LINQ to Objects).

I don't know of an equivalent for the non-generic `IEnumerable` - although you could implement such a method yourself easily enough. In C# it would look something like this:

```
public static int Count(IEnumerable source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    }

    // Optimization for ICollection implementations (e.g. arrays, ArrayList)
    ICollection collection = source as ICollection;
    if (collection != null)
    {
        return collection.Count;
    }

    IEnumerator iterator = source.GetEnumerator();
    try
    {
        int count = 0;
        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
    finally
    {
        IDisposable disposable = iterator as IDisposable;
        if (disposable != null)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that disposing of the iterator at the end is important - but you can't use a `using` statement as `IEnumerator` itself doesn't implement `IDisposable` (unlike `IEnumerator<T>`).

Of course you could either use that as C# in a class library to call from IronPython, or translate the code into IronPython yourself.

Comment: You're right, it's actually `IEnumerable<T>`. Forgot there was a difference. Thanks!

Comment: You should also look for `ICollection<T>` because some collections implement one interface but not the other.

Comment: @Gabe: I was assuming that if it was a generic collection Mark would use Enumerable.Count instead :) Checking for `ICollection<T>` would be relatively tricky here, because we don't have a `T` to test for. You'd need to go into reflection, and it gets somewhat messy.